# The htaccess file in my root is redirecting my wordpress site in my /apply/ directory to my root index. Help! :\

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My domain is https://domainremoved.com/. I installed some new software onto my site and it required that I enable mod_rewrite. It was already enabled on the server but I was told I had to also include it in my htaccess file. I also needed to install the software in the root of my site, where my wordpress blog originally was. So I moved my Wordpress blog to a new directory, and named it /apply. It was working fine, until I enabled mod_rewrite by adding this to the root htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex router.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?_doroute=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, going to my Wordpress directory redirects to my root page. Please help :\

Also, **going to https://domainremoved.com/apply/contact-page/ and other pages all works.**

This is the htaccess file info from my Wordpress directory (/apply):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apply/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /apply/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Okay, I was told by my host that the line that is causing the issue is DirectoryIndex router.php, though I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, thank God! I just had to add /apply/index.php to the .htaccess file. Here's how it looks like now:

```
DirectoryIndex router.php /apply/index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?_doroute=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 3rd rewrite condition, then clear your browser cache.

Change your .htaccess in the root to:

```
DirectoryIndex router.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?_doroute=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No luck. The root still works though without a mod_rewrite error. Take a look at my edit, by the way.

Comment: I copied and pasted the above and updated it. Still no luck. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: It's OK, that's what we're here for. Can we have your domain?

Comment: Yep. My domain is https://thespartaninstitute.com/

The wordpress site is on HTTPS, not sure if that matters.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full contents of your root .htaccess? Nice design, btw.

Comment: Haha, that's the default theme that the developers are working on. Wait until you see the blog design!

What you see is the full contents of my root .htaccess (though I am currently running your updated one right now)

Comment: Haha. Try removing DirectoryIndex router.php.

Comment: After I do that, I get this error on the front page of my site. However, my wordpress site works fine! Quite the dilemma:

If you see this page you have:
- Not enabled mod rewrite (.htaccess files must function!), ask your host to do that.

Comment: Try re-adding that. I can't work out why this isn't working. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Okay, I was told by my host that the line that is causing the issue is DirectoryIndex router.php, though I don't know how to fix that.